# Symfony2 : doctrine2 - "targetEntity" from another bundle with MultiDatabase

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Entity 1

```
    <?php

namespace Operat\SystemBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Operat\AgentsBundle\Entity\Agents;
/**
* Liensao
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Operat\SystemBundle\Entity\LiensaoRepository")
*/
class Liensao
{

       // Liensao - Agents
  /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Operat\AgentsBundle\Entity\Agents", inversedBy="liensao")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="colAgent_Code", referencedColumnName="CODE")
  */
  protected $agent;

  /*....*/
```

Entity 2

```
    <?php

    namespace Operat\AgentsBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Operat\SystemBundle\Entity\Liensao;
    /**
    * Agents
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="agents", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="Valide", columns={"Valide"}), @ORM\Index(name="GL", columns={"GL"}), @ORM\Index(name="NSOC", columns={"NSOC"})})
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
    class Agents
    {

           // Agents - Liensao
      /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Operat\SystemBundle\Entity\Liensao", mappedBy="agent")
      */
      protected $liensao;
```

Yet running
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --em=entities_system --dump-sql --force

gives the following error:

**[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
The class 'Operat\AgentsBundle\Entity\Agents' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Operat\SystemBundle\Entity, Operat\AdministrationBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Entity**

Config.yml

```
orm:
       auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
       default_entity_manager:   entities_system
       entity_managers:
           entities_system:
               connection:       operat_system
               mappings:
                   OperatSystemBundle: ~
                   FOSUserBundle: ~
           entities_agents:
               connection:       operat_agents
               mappings:
                   OperatAgentsBundle: ~
```

Comment: Shouldn't the class path be prefixed with a backslash: `\Operat\AgentsBundle\Entity\Agents`?

Comment: i did the prefix for mapping of Doctrine.Orm.EntitiesManager {entities_agents} ; But the tables angent and liensAo are created in the System database , on the other  i want that liensAo the "System" base   and Agents in the base "Agents"
Thanks for the response ^^